# How to count number of rows per group greater than the average of that group in pandas group by?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df and I use several columns from it to groupby:

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']].groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

In the above way I  get the table (data frame) that I need. What is missing is an additional column that contains number of rows in each group greater than mean(average) of that group. in fact I want something like:

```
col1  col2 mean   count  above_Mean
A      E    4      10     6    
       F    3      20     4 
B      G    7      30     15
```

I tried above return command which gives me everything except the above mean count of per group.

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']].groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

output:

```
col1  col2 mean   count  above_Mean
A      E    4      10     6    
       F    3      20     4 
B      G    7      30     15
```

Comment: Why does your output only have mean and count for a single column, when it should have 2 columns? Do you want to sum them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also aggregate using a `lambda` function as the following:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg(['mean', 'count', 
                                  lambda x: (x > x.mean()).sum()])
```